# How does Facebook remember my password?

Tags: php, facebook

Usually when I destroy my History (cache, active sessions, cookies, etc) all my "Remember Password" is deleted on diverse sites - But not on Facebook. Why? How?

How does their "Remember Password" system work?

Comment: which browser you are using ?

Comment: Facebook can't do that, and they don't. Do you have any autofill browser plugins/extensions or anything of that sort?

Comment: please make sure your security and privacy settings parameters are correct,uncheck the remember password option.(settings differ from browser to browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember me, is stored in a cookie. If you delete your cookies it will log you out. Have a look at the current domains cookies using your browsers development features and make sure you have deleted them as it doesn't sound like you have.

Answer (score 0):

it makes use of the cookies present in your browser

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your security and privacy settings parameters are correct,uncheck the remember password option.(settings differ from browser to browser)